New tag watch redesign uses the full wiki (without formatting) in the modal instead of using the tag wiki excerpt
The new "watch tag" design has apparently rolled out to Stack Overflow (only). Where previously, hovering a tag on a question would show the wiki excerpt (which is designed precisely for that kind of display), there is a bug where now the modal shows the first sentence/paragraph of the full wiki description, sometimes with broken formatting:
New tag modal (notice the huge repetitive tag name and the apparent run-on sentence in the tag description):

Tag wiki page, showing excerpt and full wiki--compare the newline formatting in the tag's wiki with the broken/missing formatting from the excerpt above):

What it used to look like (e.g. on Meta):

Can this please be reverted back to showing the excerpt (and can we get rid of repeating the tag name in big bold letters?)? Site (network?) guidelines for excerpts are crafted differently specifically to phrase them appropriately for display in this and a couple other locations, and the full description has no such requirements. Ideally, the only thing that should have changed with this rollout is replacing the 'watch tag/ignore tag' buttons with the 'follow tag' button... nothing else.
(note, this is only implemented on the main SO site, not Meta SO, Meta SE, or other network sites as far as I can tell).

This is already in the announced experiment with tags:
Upcoming sign-up experiments related to tags

Experiment 2: Updating the tag hover
We will be running an A/B/C test when users hover over tags. We intend to test whether simplifying the hover and making the call-to-action more evident will encourage more users to watch tags.
There will be three variants that both anonymous and registered users will see:

As you may notice, variants B and C show slightly shorter tag descriptions. For the purposes of this experiment, we’ll be grabbing the first line from the full tag wiki and using it in this context, but should the experiment prove successful, we’ll need to think of a better long-term solution. In the context of tagging questions (either when asking a question, or editing it), the current excerpt, along with the usage guidance present in it, will still be used even during the experiment.
Additionally, you’ll notice that we are testing copy changes with the call to action with “Watch tag” and “Follow tag.”

So technically: status-by-design

Thanks, that's awful. I have left an answer there, but naturally there's a pre-announced multi-week window between when they start ignoring responses to that post and when they implement the actual experiment... facedesk.

Yeah, well, B and C are completely useless when I have a Question open... (to look at it, and the Answerss, and maybe vote on the Quality...) I then hover over Tags to see the Tag Excerpts and check that Askers selected the correct Tags and followed the Usage Guidance which is only mentioned in the Tag Excerpt. And this has always been the intended use for the Tag Excerpt. And it becomes completely cumbersome if I now have to open all (up to 5 Tags) in (5) separate Tabs for just one same Question, just to be able to read the Excerpts. // [I'm getting C myself in this "Experiment"...]

This is even worse in the 'Staging Ground', where as Reviewers, we "definitely" need to check that the Asker has selected the correct Tags... And from the main SG View, the Tag Popup is now even truncated on the left.

For reference: link to the answer TylerH posted on the linked question

This is particularly awful for tags like [tag:seo] that are mostly off topic.  I added an answer to the meta discussion here but it seems like it's too late.  Should I open a new meta discussion about guidance for such tags?
